# Big Omega number theory representation

Tags: algorithms

[image]

Source-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Is the highlighted portion in red right?

> $\forall$$n_0$ $\exists$$n>n_0$

It should be opposite(for all and for some should be interchanged). Please clarify If I am getting wrong here.

Comment: You are thinking of the definition from complexity theory/cs, which is in fact given in the line below the portion you highlighted in red - see the image above.

Comment: In terms of interpretation, this is basically the difference between "$f(n)\geq k g(n)$ infinitely often" vs. $f(n)\geq k g(n)$ eventually always." The 3rd column in your picture gives a good description of the difference between both contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The portion highlighted in red looks correct.  The correction you suggest gives a different definition of the $\Omega$ notation.  In fact, just see the line below the portion you highlighted.  This second version is a stronger requirement since $f(n)$ must be larger than $kg(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$ (i.e. for all $n$ starting from some value $n_0$) rather than just for infinitely many values of $n$.